# Python - Add new curve from a df into existing lineplot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I create a plot using `sns` base on a `DafaFrame`.

Now, I would like to add new curve from another dataframe on the plot created previusly.

This is the code of my plot:

```
tline = sns.lineplot(x='reads', y='time', data=df, hue='method', style='method', markers=True, dashes=False, ax=axs[0, 0])
tline.set_xlabel('Numero di reads')
tline.set_ylabel ('Time [s]')
tline.legend(loc='lower right')
tline.set_yscale('log')
tline.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x')
tline.autoscale(enable=True, axis='y')
```

Now I have another `Dataframe` with the same column of the first `DataFrame`. How can I add this new curve with a custom entry in the legend?

This is the structure of the `DataFrame`:

| Dataset | Method | Reads | Time | Peak-memory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14M | Set | 14000000 | 7.33 | 1035204 |
| 20K | Set | 200000 | 0.38 | 107464 |
| 200K | Set | 20000 | 0.07 | 42936 |
| 2M | Set | 28428648 | 16.09 | 2347740 |
| 28M | Set | 2000000 | 1.41 | 240240 |

Comment: can you please provide sample data of the Data Frames?

Comment: @RoseGod I update the question

Comment: thanks, is Dataset the column that repeats in both Data Frame?

Comment: @RoseGod The DataFrame have the same columns. The second one have the same value alse in the column `method`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use matplotlibs OOP [interface](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/matplotlib/matplotlib_object_oriented_interface.htm) like this

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns


# generate sample data
time_column = np.arange(10)
data_column1 = np.random.randint(0, 10, 10)
data_column2 = np.random.randint(0, 10, 10)

# store in pandas dfs
df1 = pd.DataFrame(zip(time_column, data_column1), columns=['Time', 'Data'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(zip(time_column, data_column2), columns=['Time', 'Data'])

f, ax = plt.subplots()

sns.lineplot(df1.Time, df1.Data, label='foo', ax=ax)
sns.lineplot(df2.Time, df2.Data, label='bar', ax=ax)

ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

which generates the following output
[image]

the important thing is that both lineplots are on the same subplot (ax in this case).